# How can I correctly format "select top 1000 * from schema.table_name;" to work in Toad 4 Apache Hadoop?

Tags: sql, apache, hadoop, format, toad

Trying to run this in Toad 4 Apache Hadoop (Hive), and it does not recognize the top function. How can I reformat this?

```
select top 1000 * from Finance.ACCT_LIST
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`LIMIT`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-LIMITClause):

```
select * from Finance.ACCT_LIST
order by somecolumn
limit 1000
```

You should add an `order by` clause if you want to get a consistent set of rows.